# C lang Bit fields described by MemoryLayout in Java

Tags: java, bit-fields

How can a C language `struct` using [Bit fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-bit-fields) be described using Java [`MemoryLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/MemoryLayout.html) API (part of [JEP 442: Foreign Function & Memory API (Third Preview)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/442))?

For example how to describe C `struct` declaration

```c
struct {
    unsigned int first;
    unsigned int second: 2;
    unsigned int third: 3;
};
```

?

When ignoring the bit fields it would be something like

```java
MemoryLayout.structLayout(
        ValueLayout.JAVA_INT.withName("first"),
        ValueLayout.JAVA_INT.withName("second"),
        ValueLayout.JAVA_INT.withName("third")
);
```

Comment: The "first" field is 32 bits wide.  The "second" field is 2 bits wide,  The "third" field is 3 bits wide.  Then there will be 27 bits of padding.  So, you can't use `JAVA_INT`.  Maybe `value_layout(2)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts So the answer would be: There is no way to describe it directly. One has to replace bit fields by `int`s and access their values using bitwise operations?

Comment: @TimRoberts Since when is `unsigned int` guaranteed to be 32 bits wide?

Comment: @czerny -- `MemoryValue.ofValueBits` allows you to specify a number of bits, but I don't know whether it allows values that are not a multiple of 8.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch wins the pedantic prize, but we all know that the C compilers for all of the major operating systems have 32-bit `unsigned int`s.  If you're using something embedded, then be aware.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry. I've learned to use `uint32_t` when I need a 32-bit `unsigned int` after many *painful* debugging sessions. I miss having hair.

Comment: @TimRoberts Could you please share link to `MemoryValue.ofValueBits` you've mentioned above? I can find it neither in [current - 21 release](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/MemoryLayout.html) nor in [upcomming - 22 release](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/MemoryLayout.html).

Comment: Hmm, it looks like that was the older design (16), and they now use a template instead, so arbitrary bit fields are not possible.